Regarding MQTT client authentication with .net applications in docker containers
I am using MQTT to communicate with mosquitto using MqttFactory() in a .net console app.
In order to introduce client authentication this time, we are verifying with a self-certificate.
I used this site and others as reference when creating the self certificate.
http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/creating-and-using-client-certificates-with-mqtt-and-mosquitto/
The final version will be run on Cent OS docker, but the development environment is Windows.
The following is what we are having trouble with right now.
When running on Windows in the development environment, I was able to connect to the mosquitto broker on the CentOS server with no problems with the console app and mosqitto_sub/pub that I am creating. However, when I run the console app binary built in the development environment on CentOS docker, an error occurs and I cannot connect to the mosquitto broker. The error is as follows
2024-04-05T05:50:33: New connection from 172.19.10.1:42092 on port 8883.
2024-04-05T05:50:33: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14FFF0C7:SSL routines:(UNKNOWN)SSL_internal:peer did not return a certificate
2024-04-05T05:50:33: Client <unknown> disconnected: Protocol error.

I tried to connect to the broker with mosquitto_sub in the docker container running the console app, but in this case the connection was successful. We also experimented with the host OS instead of the docker container, but even in that case, the .net console app still failed to connect to the broker, and mosquitto_sub succeeded in connecting.
In other words, regardless of whether the console app was docker or not, it did not seem to be able to connect to the broker if it was run on CentOS.
I tried adding the following options when creating the console app, but the situation did not change.
CertificateValidationHandler = e =>{return true;}
Other situations are as follows.

The common name when creating server.csr is the FQDN of the server (abc.com in the example in the figure).
The ca.crt used for self-certification is stored in the certificate store for all Windows, CentOS, and docker containers.
In all experiments, we used abc.com as the hostname of the broker.
In the docker container, I tried to connect using the container name, but it still fails.


Is there anything we can do to improve this?
